# json error: parsererror

Tags: php, javascript, json, validation, jsonlint

I am developing a balloon notification for my social network. I came across this error when there's 2 or more notifications. I checked my JSON response on [jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com), and I got error at line 6.

JSON response:

```
    {
    "nid": "1101",
    "img": "<img src=\".\/images\/icons\/he_wall_post_icon.png\">",
    "notifier": "Sarah O&#039;conner",
    "url": " has commened on your <a href=\"wall_action.php?id=1463\">post<\/a>"
}{
    "nid": "1100",
    "img": "<img src=\".\/images\/icons\/he_wall_post_icon.png\">",
    "notifier": "Sarah O&#039;conner",
    "url": " likes your <a href=\"wall_action.php?id=1463\">post<\/a>"
}
```

here's my PHP part:

```
$ret_arr = array('nid' => $nid2,'img' => $img, 'notifier' => $notifier, 'url' => $url);

echo json_encode($ret_arr);
```

here's my JS part:

```
    function noob()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'notifications.php?n=1',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert('Success!');
        },
        error: function(requeset, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error:'+textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

How can i get that done!

Thanks guys.

Comment: which line is it where the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is missing the list brackets and the comma between objects.

It should look like:

```
[
  {
    "nid": "1101",
    "img": "<img src=\".\/images\/icons\/he_wall_post_icon.png\">",
    "notifier": "Sarah O&#039;conner",
    "url": " has commened on your <a href=\"wall_action.php?id=1463\">post<\/a>"
  },
  {
    "nid": "1100",
    "img": "<img src=\".\/images\/icons\/he_wall_post_icon.png\">",
    "notifier": "Sarah O&#039;conner",
    "url": " likes your <a href=\"wall_action.php?id=1463\">post<\/a>"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste your JSON into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) - it's a JSON validator that shows you what and where exactly is your problem and whether is valid or not.

Matthew is right, this is just a hint how to find it by yourself if you run into the same problem next time.